# Which one is more idiomatic: "until june this year." OR "in the year to june."?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

This is from the BBC website. [UK net migration hits all-time record](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-63743259)

**UK net migration hit 504,000 in the year to June.**

As English is not my native language, I would probably say **"until June this year"** rather than "**in the year to june."**

Would it be not idiomatic if I said "until June this year"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your suggested alternative does not mean the same as the original BBC text.

It has been pointed out by David K that 'the year to June' in the BBC story may be ambiguous. The source of the figure, the [UK Government Office of National Statistics](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/internationalmigration/bulletins/longterminternationalmigrationprovisional/yearendingjune2022#:%7E:text=Net%20migration%20for%20the%20UK%20in%20the%20year%20ending%20June%202022&text=This%20was%20estimated%20to%20be,compared%20with%20YE%20June%202021.), says:

> 6. Population change
>
> Net migration for the UK in the year ending June 2022
>
> Net international migration, which is the difference calculated
> between immigration and emigration within the same period, added to
> the UK population in the year ending (YE) June 2022. This was
> estimated to be at 504,000, an increase of 331,000 compared with the
> YE June 2021 (173,000).

'The **year to** June' in a story dated today 'November 24 2022' here means 'the 12-month period that ended with June 2022'. The graph included with the story makes this clear. It shows an increasing trend in 12 month periods ending in the months of June 2020, 2021, and 2022.

'Until June this year' would just mean 'an unspecified period of time that ended in June 2022'.

To clarify, in the 12 months to June 2022, the figure for people immigrating long-term into the UK was around 1,100,000. The figure for people emigrating long-term out of the UK was around 560,000. The net figure (around 504,000 immigrating) was obtained by subtracting the smaller figure from the larger one.

Comment: This may be a British English vs. US English thing, but I find "the year to June" ambiguous and (in the absence of other clues) would guess it probably meant the first six months of the current calendar year. For the 12-month period that ended with June I would say "the year ending in June."

Comment: @DavidK - Yes. The UK Office of National Statistics, from where the Guardian must have got the figure, says 'Net migration for the UK in the year ending June 2022: 
Net international migration, which is the difference calculated between immigration and emigration within the same period, added to the UK population in the **year ending (YE)** June 2022. ' (my bold emphasis)

Comment: In light of that, maybe it's not so much a British/US thing as a difference between the precise language of a statistical publication and the (frequently) less precise language of a newspaper article.

Comment: @DavidK - I have added your point to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidK it's a BBC News website story (not a Guardian one as I said above in a comment).

Comment: @DarthPseudonym - where I work (UK, finance) 'year to date', with or without hyphens, or 'YTD', means '**from the first day of the current year** (whether the fiscal, tax, or calendar year, which is specified or understood in the context) **to the present date**', (that's what 'to date' means) and this seems to be the common usage elsewhere too.

Answer (score 7):

Your version is incorrect, but it's a very common issue with "until".

"Until" means the complete main clause was true or happening continuously starting some time in the past and finishing at the time indicated, after which time it stopped doing it or it stopped being true.

In your example, this means UK net migration was *continuously hitting 504,000 again and again* for the 12 month period starting July 1 of last year and finishing June 30 of this year. After June 30, it either started hitting a different number, or stopped hitting any number.

Generally speaking, we use "until" to describe things that stopped being true or stopped happening at some specific time. We tend to use other forms to indicate time spans.

Comment: I understand the point. Thanks that was informative. So, instead of until, can we say "UK net migration hit 504,000 by june this year."

Comment: @yunus Exactly.

Comment: The figures mean that a net figure of 504,000 people immigrated into the UK between June 2021 and June 2022.

Comment: Oh, I am confused. I thought it referred to 6 months from the start of the year 2021, ending in June. So, that was why I had said "...Until June this year", thinking that it would refer to the beginning of the year until the end of June. But now I understand, it would be wrong.

Comment: @yunus - They would write 'this year up to June' if that is what they meant.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Thanks for the answer, however, it is interesting that a similar question is asked in other forums, and again there are 2 kinds of answers. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220268/in-the-year-to-november-meaning

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Here is another one: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-the-year-to-april.3353881/

Comment: @yunus - I don't agree with the 2015 ELL SE answer which said 'the "year to December" refers only to the first 11 months of the year. If they had wanted to include December they would have said something like "for the year" or "for 1999" etc.'.

Comment: @gotube -the latter. The UK Gov statistical year runs in quarters. The last two of one calendar year (i.e Jul-Aug-Sep & Oct-Nov-Dec) and the first two of the next calendar year (Jan-Feb-Mar & Apr-May-June).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks. Fixed